# Async-Await expression returns wrong result

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, .net-4.5

I have a problem with async-await expression which returns wrong result.

```
private Task<int> A
{
    get
    {
        return TaskEx.RunEx<int>(async () =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            return 2;
        });
    }
}

private Task<int> B
{
    get
    {
        return TaskEx.RunEx<int>(async () =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(4000);
            return 4;
        });
    }
}

private string SumAll(int a, int b)
{
    return (a + b).ToString();
}
```

Now, when I want to sum properties A and B by launching SumAll method I get the result 4 where I should get 6. Below you can find a code which does not work.

```
private async void Sum_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Result.Text = this.SumAll(await A, await B);
}
```

When, I do the same example with the method below I got the right result.

```
private async void Sum_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var a = await A;
    var b = await B;
    this.Result.Text = this.SumAll(a, b);
}
```

BTW. I know that the best way would be to use WhenAll method, but I am learing.
Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a known bug with the CTP ([my blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/06/10/eduasync-part-10-ctp-bug-don-t-combine-multiple-awaits-in-one-statement.aspx); [Lucian Wischik's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2011/04/17/async-ctp-refresh-what-bugs-remain-in-it.aspx)). It'll be fixed in the full release.